# How can I send form data to test.html by using asynchronous communication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I wanna send form data to test.html by using asynchronous communication.
I wrote in index.html

```
<body>
　  <form method="post" action="">
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

    {% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id=type{{forloop.counter}}>
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainDD').on('change', function() {
              var thisType = "type" + $(this).val();
              for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
                  var thisId = "type" + i;
                  if(thisType !== thisId) {
                    $("#"+thisId).hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $("#"+thisId).show();
                  }
              }

            }).trigger('change');

        });


  </script>

     <form id="postform" action="http://localhost:8000/app/test_view" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="SEND">
     </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $('[name=type]').change(function() {
            var array1 = [];
            var array2 =[];
                $('[name=main] option:selected').each(function() {
                array1 = $(this).text();
                console.log(array1);
            });

                $('[name=type] option:selected').each(function() {
                array2 = $(this).text();
                console.log(array2);
            });
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout:3000,
            async: true,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.newsarea').html(html).fadeIn(5000);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
     </script>
  </body>
```

I wanna send selected i & value's variables to test.html.Now when I put send button,nothing is shown in test.html.
I wrote test.html like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RESULT</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>TOPIC</h2>
<div class="newsarea">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I wanna show selected i & value's values in this place of .What is wrong in my code?How can I fix this?

Comment: When should the value be sent to `test.html`? How do you know that `test.html` is being visited by user?

Comment: I wanna send these value to test.html when I put send button.I cannot understand ur 2nd question.Could u write more in detail?

Comment: When is `test.html` visited by user?

Comment: @guest271314 it is when user put send button

Comment: You really should read about what you're doing and not copy random code from internet without understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `document` originates from same origin as original `document` and is opened by user action you can pass the parameters as a query string.

```
  document.querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick = e => {
    // pass key, value pairs to `test.html`
    const test = window.open(`test.html?${key}=${value}`, "_blank");
  }
```

at opened `window` get and parse `location.search`

```
  onload = () => {
    // do stuff with key, value pairs passed from `window.opener`
    console.log([...new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()])
  }
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/MlCQZpkfBXFwxdR6gz5x?p=preview

Comment: thx ur comments.Where should I write these 2 codes?index.html's script tag of  js,right?

Comment: The first code should be within HTML `document` which opens `"test.html"`. The second code should be at `"test.html"`

Comment: thx ur comments,i read plank,and I wrote ur codes.But in test.html only csrfmiddlewaretoken & random letters&number is shown not variable `i`&`value`.How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `csrmiddlewaretoken`?

Comment: Now test.html shows csrfmiddlewaretoken,MWe8s6ylBOG4qaR3l0nsZPHSfEhANSGflzfI6ZCRaDMDJKix7A2aSAzvm3DOnXpP  in the place of <script> tag

Comment: That is beyond the scope of the original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve