# Redirect a Popup and Post Message

Tags: javascript, post, popup, window, postmessage

I am stuck in a problem where i have to redirect from a popup window to a different domain and post a message to it. 
Here is the scenario :-

1. User opens a new popup window which stays in same domain.(ex: http://doamin_one.com)
2. User fills the form in the popup window and clicks submit. This should redirect the window to http://doamin_two.com and domain_two.com should receive form data via post message.

I am able to receive messages if i open fresh popup and do post message but not in the case of redirection. Here is my code:

http://domain_one.com -

```
   function redirect(formData,popup) {
     //popup=window ref object
     popup.location.href="http://domain_two.com"
     popup.postMessage(JSON.stringify(formData),
          "http://domain_two.com");
}
```

http://domain_two.com -

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event)
{
 if (event.origin !== "http://domain_one.com")
      return;
 let data=event.data;
 //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the form data to `"http://domain_two.com"` using query string parameters then parse the query string of `location.href` at `load` event of the second domain

```
popup.location.href = `http://domain_two.com?${new URLSearchParams(formData.entries()).toString()}`
```

Comment: Form Data can get pretty big and data transfer has to be secure. Is there any other way?

Comment: @JSGeek Can you include the code at `"http://domain_two.com"` at the question? `postMessage()` is called immediately, before the `window` has loaded. The request is also cross-domain.

Comment: I have updated my question with code. Using setTimeout for post message dint help either.

Comment: How do you know when `"http://domain_two.com"` is loaded? `popup.postMessage(JSON.stringify(formData),
          "http://domain_two.com")` is called immediately after `popup.location.href="http://domain_two.com"` at the code at the question.

Comment: What do u recommend

Comment: @JSGeek You could try using `Storage`, `history`,  `MessageChannel` and `iframe` elements or a `SharedWorker` , `ServiceWorker`. Or communicating with `opener` by substituting `window.open()` for setting `popup` `.href`. Essentially the code at the question attempts to `postMessage()` to itself. The simplest approach would be to parse the query string at `load` event of new `window`.

Comment: @JSGeek See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127985/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461819/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810002/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46337968/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/

Answer (score 0):

One issue with the code at the question is that `.postMessage()` is called immediately following setting a new `.location.href` at `popup` without waiting for the `load` event of `window` at

```
 popup.location.href="http://domain_two.com"
 popup.postMessage(JSON.stringify(formData),
      "http://domain_two.com");
```

To achieve the expected result you can control the process from the original `window` ('index.html'). Each `window.name` is set to a unique value. When the `<form>` is submitted at  `"http://domain_one.com"` the resulting `FormData` can be converted to an `ArrayBuffer` and transferred to `index.html`, then `popup` (`a.html`)  `location.href` is set to `"http://domain_two.com"`. At `load` event of `b.html` `.postMessage()` the `name` of the `window` to `index.html`. Then the `FormData` is passed to `.postMessage()` where `b.html` gets the `FormData` that was originally submitted at `b.html`.

(The `origin` checks might need to be adjusted at the below code. The code was tested at plnkr, where simulation of cross-domain messaging is not 1:1, though should provide a pattern for how to accomplish the requirement).

index.html (`opener`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // open `popup`
    const popup = window.open('a.html'); 
    // create random values to assign to `name` at `a.html` and `b.html`
    const [firstName, lastName] = [...Array(2)].map(_ => new Uint32Array(16));
    [firstName, lastName].forEach(buffer => window.crypto.getRandomValues(buffer));
    const [decoder, encoder] = [new TextDecoder(), new TextEncoder()];
    const [first, last] = [firstName, lastName].map(buffer => decoder.decode(buffer));
    // set `name` of `popup` (`a.html`) to `first`
    popup.name = first;
    let data;
    window.addEventListener("message", e => {
      // check `name` of `source` 
      if (e.source.name === first) {
        console.log(e.source.name);    
        // store `formData`        
        data = decoder.decode(e.data);
        console.log(e, JSON.parse(decoder.decode(e.data)));
        // set `name` of `popup` to `last`
        popup.name = last;
        // redirect `popup` to `b.html`
        popup.location.href = "b.html";
      }
      // check if `name` of `source` (`b.html`) is `last` 
      if (e.source.name === last) {
        // encode the stored `formData`
        let curr = encoder.encode(data);
        console.log(e.source.name, e.data);
        // transfer `formData` to `b.html`
        e.source.postMessage(curr.buffer, e.source.location.href, [curr.buffer]);
        // data = void 0;
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html (`popup`, `"http://domain_one.com"`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  a
  <form>
    <input name="input">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = e => {
      // prevent default `form` submission
      e.preventDefault();
      // pass `form` to `FormData` 
      const formData = new FormData(e.target);
      // encode `formData` as a `Uint8Array`
      const encoded = new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify([...formData.entries()]));
      console.log(encoded);
      // transfer `encoded` to `opener` (`index.html`)
      opener.postMessage(encoded.buffer, opener.location.href, [encoded.buffer]);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html (`popup`, `"http://domain_two.com"`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  b
  <script>
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let data;
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    function receiveMessage(event) {
      // check `origin` of `event`
      if (event.origin !== opener.location.origin)
        return;
      console.log(event);
      // process `formData` from `popup`
      data = JSON.parse(decoder.decode(event.data));
      // do stuff with `formData`
      p.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    }
    // wait for `load` event to be dispatched before posting message to `opener`
    onload = () => {
      opener.postMessage("ok", opener.location.href);
    }
  </script>
  <pre id="p"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3uzTpyT8VELQqO0Hrtxg?p=preview)

Comment: Pretty sure this way won't work cross-domain because once you hit the 'opener' calls, you will get cross-origin frame exceptions.